# How to persistently cache data fetched from remote server with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, axios, etag

I am building a reactjs (with hooks) web app which presents the user some data fetched from remote server pages (using a simple proxy).
Data on remote server changes about once per week, so I would like to persistently cache data (for example using LocalStorage) on the client, until server side pages are not updated, for a better user experience.

I'm using `axios` for data fetching, but I could also use a basic `fetch`.

The problem is that I can't understand how to cache data on the client *until any update on the server*: I see for example `axios` supports caching mechanisms (also using `interceptors`), but no way I can specify something like `ETag` or `If-None-Match` request header, but I can only  specifiy a fixed amount of time before the cache is invalidated.

It is possible I'm missing something obvious, and that I'm asking something unfeasible...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways solving this:

1) using a DDP protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Data_Protocol or some polling mechanism (e.g. fetch every x minutes)

2) add some "expireAt" timestamp in the response itself and use that one on the client to figure out when to check again for updates

3) using websockets with some pub/sub mechanism

They all have their ups and downs and you'd need to check if they are feasible for your application.

Best,
Sebo

Comment: Perhaps my question was not so clear, sorry... 1) I don't want to sync the client to the server... Just trying to avoid unnecessary data transfers... 2) I do not control the server, so I cannot add anything in the response... 3) I don't want to use any pub/sub mechanism, for the same reason as point 1...